# Define CSS styling for specific font families

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I just wanted to know if it was possible to define CSS styles for certain font families within CSS. I'm open to Javascript solutions as well.

For example, I want to decrease letter-spacing on a particular font, but if one of the fallback fonts are used, I don't want to apply this letter-spacing.

Comment: Are you going to add the fonts yourself or regular fonts like arial or helvetica?

Comment: Difficult. Even if you know which font the browser thinks it's using, it might still not be the exact font you think it is. For instance if you use 'Times' in your CSS, the browser will think it uses 'Times', but the system will replace this by 'Nimbus Roman No9', 'Liberation Serif' or even 'Times New Roman', which the browser is totally unaware of.

Comment: It is a font that I am supplying with @font-face, so I'd have the control to make sure I'm pointing at the right font. It still sounds like I'd have trouble identifying what font is in use, even with Javascript? I was just hoping there was some kind of CSS trick I could utilize to attach styling to a font-family, but it doesn't sound like there is :\

Comment: If you know exactly which font it is, it shouldn't be a problem. I believe that with things like LESS, you can have functions that change both the font family and the letter spacing.